# Change icon in childlist of Expandabllistview when onClick icon in android

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

Now i am working with ExpandableListview in android.
In ExpabdableListview GroupHeader contain one textview.
and Child contain one Textview and one Button.
In Button i have setbackground white star.

I have also use BaseExpandableListAdapter class to set the data in expandablelistview.

**My Question**

when click in particular child list button that time that button background change. White to Yellow.

Please any one have idea to change the color of specific button ?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to respond without any code presented in your question, but idea can be the following:

- In your adapter, maintain list of 'clicked' child;
- In `getChildView()` check if items is clicked and set proper background image;

Example code would look the following:

```
// for ViewHolder pattern
private static class ViewHolder {
    // Child item views
    public Button button;

    public long combinedId;
}

private static class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    private LongSparseArray<Boolean> mClickedItems = new LongSparseArray<Boolean>();

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, final boolean isLastChild, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (view == null) {
            // Inflate child view

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.combinedId = getCombinedChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (mClickedItems.get(holder.combinedId, false)) {
            holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_clicked_background);
        } else {
            holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clicked_background);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        final long id = ((ViewHolder)v.getTag()).combinedId;
        Boolean clicked = mClickedItems.get(id);

        if (clicked == null) {
            clicked = true;
        } else {
            clicked = !clicked;
        }

        mClickedItems.append(id, clicked);
    }

    // Rest of adapter
}
```

Also, it might be better to use `ToogleButton` instead of normal button.